# Aliases and Group By Statements in SAS Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I am working with proc SQL in SAS and one of my proc sql queries is behaving very oddly:

I have a large data set (about 1 Million rows), which looks something like this:

```
apple_key    profit    price    cost    months    date      
golden_d     0.03      12       4       3         01/12
golden_d     0.03      8        0       2         01/12
granny_s     0.05      15       5       5         02/12
red_d        0.04      13       0       1         01/12
golden_d     0.02      1        2       12         03/14
```

On this data set I am running the following query:

```
%let picking_date = 01/12; /* I simplify here - this part of my code definitely works */

proc sql; 
    CREATE TABLE output AS 
    SELECT 
        (CASE apple_key
              WHEN "golden_d" THEN 1
              WHEN "granny_s" THEN 2
              WHEN "red_d"    THEN 3
        END) AS apple_id,
        apple_key AS apple_name,
        (CASE WHEN cost= 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END) AS cost_flag,
        (CASE 
            WHEN CEIL(months / 2) < 5 THEN CEIL(months / 2) 
            ELSE 5
        END) AS age, 
        "McDonalds" as farm, 
        sum(profit*price)/sum(price) as price_weighted_profit
    FROM input_table
    WHERE date = "&picking_date."d
        AND price > cost
        AND cost >= 0
        AND cost >= 0
    GROUP BY apple_id, apple_name, cost_flag, age, farm
    ; 
run;
```

When I run this my `GROUP BY`statement does not work. I get a bunch of entries 
for a single group (where apple_id, apple_name, cost_flag, age and farm are all the same, but my aggregation is not working).

However, when I run the GROUP BY separately (as follows) everything works perfectly fine. I get one entry for each group with a "price weighted profit":

```
proc sql; 
    CREATE TABLE output_tmp AS 
    SELECT 
        (CASE apple_key
              WHEN "golden_d" THEN 1
              WHEN "granny_s" THEN 2
              WHEN "red_d"    THEN 3
        END) AS apple_id,
        apple_key AS apple_name,
        (CASE WHEN cost= 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END) AS cost_flag,
        (CASE 
            WHEN CEIL(months / 2) < 5 THEN CEIL(months / 2) 
            ELSE 5
        END) AS age, 
        "McDonalds" as farm
    FROM input_table
    WHERE date = "&picking_date."d
        AND price > cost
        AND cost >= 0
        AND cost >= 0
   ;

    CREATE TABLE output AS
    SELECT 
        apple_id, 
        apple_name, 
        cost_flag, 
        age, 
        farm,
        sum(profit*price)/sum(price) as price_weighted_profit
    FROM output_tmp
    GROUP BY apple_id, apple_name, cost_flag, age, farm
    ;
quit;
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it? This is driving me a little bit crazy... Thanks up front for the help

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the count or sum by doing a group by?

Comment: Sorry. Had forgotten to move the summary function statement to the second `create table´ statement. Should be correct now. I am trying to calculate "price_weighted_profit" here

Comment: What output do you expect from your sample input? What output are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because group by is not taking sum(profit*price)/sum(price) statement as aggregated function. it does not do that because of aliases like age, cost_flag etc.

Anyways below is the right query:-

```
 Proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE output AS 
     SELECT 
            apple_id, 
            apple_name, 
            cost_flag, 
            age, 
            farm, 
            sum(profit*price)/sum(price) as price_weighted_profit
        FROM
       (
        SELECT 
            (CASE apple_key
                  WHEN "golden_d" THEN 1
                  WHEN "granny_s" THEN 2
                  WHEN "red_d"    THEN 3
            END) AS apple_id,
            apple_key AS apple_name,
            (CASE WHEN cost= 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
            END) AS cost_flag,
            (CASE 
                WHEN CEIL(months / 2) < 5 THEN CEIL(months / 2) 
                ELSE 5
            END) AS age, 
            "McDonalds" as farm
        FROM input_table
        WHERE date = "&picking_date."d
            AND price > cost
            AND cost >= 0
            AND cost >= 0

        ) a
        GROUP BY apple_id, apple_name, cost_flag, age, farm;
        quit;
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks so much. This one solved everything. Just to make sure I understand: an `alias` is what I get every time I use an `AS` statement These aliases are preventing the `GROUP BY` statement from grouping correctly. Could you help me understand why this is happening? As in: why doesn't it recognize my aliases?

Comment: yup. your understanding is correct. That's a bug or I don't know that's how SAS works. Gotta live with it

Answer (score 0):

Thumb rule :- Whenever you use any aggregate functions in your select clause the remaining columns should be part of the group by. In your question you posted you are apply **sum(profit*price)/sum(price)** but there is no group by which is causing the problem.

```
Proc sql;
    CREATE TABLE output AS 
        SELECT 
            (CASE apple_key
                  WHEN "golden_d" THEN 1
                  WHEN "granny_s" THEN 2
                  WHEN "red_d"    THEN 3
            END) AS apple_id,
            apple_key AS apple_name,
            (CASE WHEN cost= 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
            END) AS cost_flag,
            (CASE 
                WHEN CEIL(months / 2) < 5 THEN CEIL(months / 2) 
                ELSE 5
            END) AS age, 
            "McDonalds" as farm, 
            sum(profit*price)/sum(price) as price_weighted_profit
        FROM input_table
        WHERE date = "&picking_date."d
            AND price > cost
            AND cost >= 0
            AND cost >= 0    
        GROUP BY apple_id, apple_name, cost_flag, age, farm;
        quit;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help, but as mentioned above I am using a `GROUP BY` in both of the versions above. One of them just doesnt seem to be working just isn`t working. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Are you able to create table with the above sql I have written?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what is happening is [remerging](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0xwc73ekemkapn1byhceqrwrisb.htm#p0p3gi8zch56min15fulykpkzv3b).  SAS proc sql accepts code like this:

```
proc sql;
    select a.*, count(*)
    from a;
```

This does not summarize the data.  Instead it puts the overall count on each row.  In other words, if the keys in the `select` don't exactly match the `group by`, then the aggregation functions are calculated based on the `group by` keys, but the results are put onto the individual rows.  Other databases do this with a subset of the window functions.

In your case, remerging is not obvious.  I think there is key confusion because you are using the same names in the `select` as in the original data.  My advice is to change the aliases so they are unambiguous and be sure that the keys in the `group by` are unambiguous.